# Strftime function

Tags: r

I am working on Rstudio and I'm trying to retrieve time from a date-time column. for example, the date-time column looks like this in my vector '2020-01-01 00:33:03'. This is only one observation I have in the column I want to extract information from.

Anyway, When I apply strftime('2020-01-01 00:33:03', '%H') and want to extract hours in this case. The function does not give me the correct hour which is in this cases 12 AM instead it gives me 16. I am not sure if there is anything I should specify further. This is New York Time idk if that helps.

I really appreciate any feedback or if there is any other functions/packages that I should use other than this one.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell where the issue is. Does "when I apply..." mean that you are using an `apply` function? Can you provide example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new york should be eastern time zone. Have you tried to first give it a timezone before acquiring the hour?

```
t <- strptime( '2020-01-01 00:33:03',                              
         format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",
         tz = "EST")

strftime(t, '%H')
```

You can acquire your actual tz also with `Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)`